# How to read configurations to a search analyzer?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

It seems to me Elasticsearch has **two analyzers**, one is for **index** and the other is for **query**.

I was successfully manage to add the index analyzer to tokenize the documents, but have no clue of adding an analyzer to the search query.

This is a preliminary file I have, written in Python

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es_conn = Elasticsearch(config.ES_HOSTS)


def analyze_query(text, es_conn, index_name):
    '''
        analyzes any text with my_analyzer defined in es_settings.json
        input:
            - text: a query text
            - es_conn: elasticsearch connection
            - index_name: name of index
        output:
            - a list of tokens
    '''

    tokens = es_conn.indices.analyze(
        index = index_name,
        body = {"text": text},
        # how to point the analyzer to the json file???
        analyzer = 'my_analyzer')["tokens"]
    return [token_row["token"].encode('utf-8') for token_row in tokens]
```

Got an error

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'illegal_argument_exception', u'[1aVYakX][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:admin/analyze[s]]')
```

The problem occurs in the `analyzer = 'my_analyzer'` part, I am not sure how to make it points to the json file which defines the Elasticsearch settings.

**Addition**

the json file

```
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "filename": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false,
          "doc_values": false
        },
        "path": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "index": false,
          "doc_values": false
        },
        "text": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `analyze` function does not take analyzer as a parameter.
More details here: http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.analyze.

Instead, you should pass `body` parameter. Replace the analyze_query function with the one below.

```
def analyze_query(text, es_conn, index_name, settings_path = config.SETTINGS_PATH):

    with open(settings_path) as json_data:
        settings = json.load(json_data)["settings"]["analysis"]

        filter_settings = settings["filter"]
        analyzer_settings = settings["analyzer"]["my_analyzer"]

        body = {}
        body["text"] = text
        body["tokenizer"] = analyzer_settings["tokenizer"]
        if "char_filter" in analyzer_settings:
          body["char_filter"] = analyzer_settings["char_filter"]

        body["filter"] = [ filter_settings[f] if f in filter_settings else f \
            for f in analyzer_settings["filter"]]
        tokens = es_conn.indices.analyze(
            index = index_name,
            body = body)["tokens"]

    return [token_row["token"].encode('utf-8') for token_row in tokens]
```

And good luck with your assignment.